# Using a variable in a function in another function in python

Tags: python, function, return, callable

I returned the variable and I still get the variable is still undefined. Can someone help?

```
def vote_percentage(s):
    '''(string) = (float)
    count the number of substrings 'yes' in
    the string results and the number of substrings 'no' in the string
    results, and it should return the percentage of "yes"
    Precondition: String only contains yes, no, and abstained'''
    s = s.lower()
    s = s.strip()
    yes = int(s.count("yes"))
    no = int(s.count("no"))
    percentage = yes / (no + yes)
    return percentage

def vote(s):
    ##Calling function
    vote_percentage(s)
    if percentage == 1.0: ##problem runs here
        print("The proposal passes unanimously.")
    elif percentage >= (2/3) and percentage < 1.0:
        print("The proposal passes with super majority.")
    elif percentage < (2/3) and percentage >= .5:
        print("The proposal passes with simple majority.")
    else:
        print("The proposal fails.")
```

Comment: Assign the return value to a variable: `percentage = vote_percentage(s)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you are implementing your code, if you define a variable in one method, you cannot access it in another.

The percentage variable inside vote_percentage is within scope of the vote_percentage method only, which means it cannot be used outside that method the way you are trying to use it.

So, in your vote_percentage you are returning percentage. Which means, that when you call this method, you need to actually assign its result to a variable.

So, to show you with an example using your code.

Looking at your code from here:

```
def vote(s):
    ##Calling function
    vote_percentage(s)
```

What you need to be doing when calling vote_percentage is actually store the return value, so you can do something like this:

```
percentage = vote_percentage(s)
```

Now, you actually have the return of vote_percentage in the variable percentage.

Here is another small example to further explain scoping for you:

If you do this:

```
def foo()
    x = "hello"
```

If you are outside the method foo(), you cannot access the variable x. It is within the "scope" of foo only. So if you do this:

```
def foo():
    x = "hello"
    return x
```

And you have another method that needs the result of foo(), you do not have access to that "x", so you need to store that return in a variable like this:

```
def boo():
    x = foo()
```

As you can see in my example, similar to your code, I even used the variable x in boo(), because it is a "different" x. It is not within the same scope as foo().

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem.

Comment: @Stephanie You are welcome. You should accept the answer so to help the next person with similar problems